# difficulty setting up bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to coding and I am trying to figure out a couple things with my new webpage. I used a bootstrap template for the Navbar. I deleted some of the links it came with and customized it to the way I like it. My problem is when I shrink the browser to mobile size, the toggle on the right appears, but when I click nothing happens. Also, when the browser is shrunk to mobile size, the list items on the Navbar get pushed to the left and they stack down. Like I said, I am very new to coding, and I am learning on my own. Here is my code.

```
<style>
    .navbar-brand {
        padding-right: 70px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .nav li {
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>



<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></li>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class= id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you also included jQuery & Bootstraps JS files?

Comment: Oh and the reason nothing happens mainly is because you have removed the `.collapse` div

Comment: where can i find these files?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by " the toggle on the right appears, but when I click nothing happens". Can you be more detailed on what you intend to archive.

Comment: So when the browser is shrunk to mobile size a drop down toggle appears on the right of the navbar. When you click on it, the list items across the navbar are supposed to drop down, but the button is unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you're not including the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library **OR** you're not placing it properly. You can [visit this link for the basic template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template) and as you can see there, the `jQuery` is including first before the `bootstrap.js`/`bootstrap.min.js`. And this part `<div class= id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">` **Should be** `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`, take note that the class `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` helps the navbar to collapse.

You may just try this, if you want to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <br>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Here's your starter template!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps! :) You can now check it a mark as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have removed the collapse class.

You have: 
`<div class= id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`

It should be: 
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></li>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

<!-- collapse -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this link in head before you have added your own css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then add the following two links at the end of body tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    .navbar-brand {
        padding-right: 70px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        height: 75px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .nav li {
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>
</head>


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></li>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class= id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</body>
```